# Create nested list from file columns (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to create a nested list using the lines of a .txt file, but can't reach my desired form.

#### .txt file content:

```
[1,2,3]  
[2,3,4]  
[3,4,5]
```

#### Code:

```
nested_List = []
file = open("example_File.txt",'r')
    for i in file:
        element = i.rstrip("\n")
        nested_List.append(element)
arch.close()
return (esta)
```

#### The result I get:

```
['[1,2,3]', '[2,3,4]', '[3,4,5]']
```

#### What I want:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the string representing the list to an actual list.  You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) like:

```
from ast import literal_eval

nested_list = []
with open("file1", 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        nested_list.append(literal_eval(i))
print(nested_list)
```

Or with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

```
with open("file1", 'r') as f:
    nested_list = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
print(nested_list)
```

#### Results:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something similar and came up with the following which uses the python's abstract syntax tree's [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function.

```
import ast
nested_List = []

with open("example_File.txt", 'r') as infile:
    for i in infile:
        element = i.rstrip("\n")
        nested_List.append(ast.literal_eval(element))

print(nested_List)
```

Comment: or what stephen-rauch said :)

Comment: there isn't much difference between your code and that of @stephen-rauch. Note that you can leave out `ast` in `ast.literal_eval(element)`